# Stripping whitespace in 2D lists

Tags: python, string, list

How do I clean this 2D list:

```
sales1=[[' Andy Turner  ',' $62  ', ' \n 25/12/21], ['Kelvin Obgona  ', ' $120  ', ' \n 01/03/22  ']]
```

into:

```
[['Andy Turner','$62','25/12/21], ['Kelvin Obgona', '$120', '01/03/22']]
```

My code:

```
sales_clean=[] 
for t1 in list1:  
sales_clean.append(sales1.strip())
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `[[val.strip() for val in row] for row in sales1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `str.strip` to each item of the list. You can use a list comprehension instead.

```py
sales_clean = [[s.strip() for s in m] for m in sales1]
```

This is equivalent to the following using only loops.

```py
sales_clean=[] 
for t1 in sales1:
    t_clean = []
    for t2 in t1:
        t_clean.append(t2.strip())
    sales_clean.append(t_clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sales1=[[' Andy Turner  ',' $62  ', ' \n 25/12/21'], ['Kelvin Obgona  ', ' $120  ', ' \n 01/03/22  ']]

#Strip spaces from 2D array the left and right of the string
for i in range(len(sales1)):
    for j in range(len(sales1[i])):
        sales1[i][j]=sales1[i][j].strip()

print(sales1)
```

or faster

```
sales2=[[x.strip() for x in y] for y in sales1]
```